# PubSub resource setup failing for Dataflow job when assigning timestampLabel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

After modifying my job to start using `timestampLabel` when reading from PubSub, resource setup seems to break every time I try to start the job with the following error:

```
(c8bce90672926e26): Workflow failed. Causes: (5743e5d17dd7bfb7): Step    setup_resource_/subscriptions/project-name/subscription-name__streaming_dataflow_internal25: Set up of resource /subscriptions/project-name/subscription-name__streaming_dataflow_internal failed
```

where `project-name` and `subscription-name` represent the actual values of my project and PubSub subscription I'm trying to read from. Before trying to attach `timestampLabel` on message entry, the job was working correctly, consuming messages from the specified PubSub subscription, which should mean that my API/network settings are OK.

I'm also noticing two warnings with the payload

```
Internal Issue (119d3b54af281acf): 65177287:8503
```

but no more information can be found in the worker logs. For the few seconds that my job is setting up I can see the `timestampLabel` being set in the first step of the pipeline. Unfortunately I can't find any other cases or documentation about this error.

Comment: What was the job ID for the failing job?

Comment: @BenChambers one of them is 2017-01-18_09_26_55-6088470432791782708. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `timestampLabel` feature, a second subscription is created for tracking purposes. Double check the permission settings on your topic to make sure it matches the [permissions required](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#accessing-pubsub-topics-and-subscriptions-across-cloud-platform-projects).

Comment: Thank you Ben! We are reading PubSub cross-project and were giving permissions on a per subscription/topic basis once those resources had been created. I had to give the second project PubSub editor rights (in the main project) in order for it to work properly.